# Solution in the distribution set

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Could you please help me to prove that the solution of

$$(1-\exp^{2i\pi x})T=0$$ in $D'(\mathbb{R})$ is $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}c_n\delta_n$ where $c_n=C$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume by $\delta_n$ you mean the shifted Dirac distribution. i.e. $i<\delta_n,\phi> = \phi(n)$.

Let $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ that is to say is smooth with compact support, then by definition we have that,

$\begin{align} 
<\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\delta_n(1-e^{2\pi i x}),\phi> &= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}<\delta_n, (1-e^{2\pi i x})\phi>\\
&= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}((1-e^{2\pi i n})\phi(n)\\
&=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}((1-1)\phi(n)=0
\end{align}$

Where the second to last equality follows from the fact that $e^{2\pi i n}=1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: in what you have written you proved that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \delta_n$ is a particular solution and this doesn’t answer my problem.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean? Do you mean to say that you want to show uniqueness of solution? Could you please expand on what exactly you want?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean I want to show the uniqueness of the solutions $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} c_n \delta_n$